# How to sort an array of Strings in Jquery with any specific sort order given

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have and array of strings:

```
var arrStr = ["Ron", "Jhon", "Mary", "Alex", "Ben"];
```

The above array is the default sort order that I require. I have another array of Strings:

```
var arrStr2 = ["Mary", "Alex", "Jhon"];
```

I wanted to sort `arrStr2` with the sort order in `arrStr`. (the order in `arrStr` also can be changed, accordingly the `arrStr2` should be sorted). `arrStr2` can have more values also, but the values will be only from any of the values in array `arrStr`

After sorting I need an out put for `arrStr2` as `["Jhon","Mary","Alex"];`

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: do you have a case where arrStr2 may have duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute the intersection, no need to `sort()`:

```js
var arrStr = ["Ron", "Jhon", "Mary", "Alex", "Ben"];
var arrStr2 = ["Mary", "Alex", "Jhon"];

result = arrStr.filter(x => arrStr2.includes(x))

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(result,0,3));
```

(ES5 backporting left as an exercise).

Comment: Assuming that it is left as an exercise for everyone (not only OP) :)  ES5 would be `arrStr2 = arrStr.filter(function(value) { return arrStr2.indexOf(value) > -1; })`

Answer (score 1):

> After sorting I need an out put for arrStr2 as ["Jhon","Mary","Alex"];

simply try this

```
arrStr2.sort(function(a,b){ return arrStr.indexOf(a) - arrStr.indexOf(b) });
```

Now `arrStr2` will have the value you are expecting,

**DEMO**

```js
var arrStr = ["Ron", "Jhon", "Mary", "Alex", "Ben"];

var arrStr2 = ["Mary", "Alex", "Jhon"];

arrStr2.sort(function(a,b){ return arrStr.indexOf(a) - arrStr.indexOf(b) });

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( arrStr2, 0, 4 );
```

Comment: Thanks !. It does the sorting, but the result is a JSON and that is which is converted to String. Now the new array which I get are having all values with extra spaces appended, which I do not need.

Answer (score 0):

This is one more approach:

```
var rank = {};
arrStr.forEach(function(e, i){rank[e] = i;});
arrStr2.sort(function(a, b) {return rank[a] - rank[b];});
```